# How do I view a zend encoded file in binary format?

Tags: php, binary, zend-guard

I have a PHP script encoded with Zend Guard, when I view it with sublime text or notepad++ it appears to be:

[image]

I think this shouldn't be how it looks, What should I change to view in binary format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you expecting? Looks good to me. The file starts with a header that is shown in case Zend Guard is not installed on the web server. Below starts your encoded script.

Comment: Well what do you want to see there? 0100010010? Your text editor interprets the 0s and 1s as blocks of eight according to its standard encoding (probably ASCII). That is the reason it shows these characters. The representation is perfectly valid though

Comment: Exactly, How do I see the 0100010010 syntax?

Comment: This list in Wikipedia has a comparison table for editors. You can check the column "bit editing" in the feature list. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors]

Comment: @t0r You should not even need to view it as binary. It is encoded and obfuscated by Zend Guard in order to protect source code from access. Binary representation will not give you any meaningful info either